# C OpenSSLRSA double encryption fails

Tags: c, openssl, rsa

I have 2 processes connected with a socket.
I use RSA to encrypt and decrypt messages.
Client have the following keys:

```
    RSA *client_private_key;
    RSA *client_public_key; 
    RSA *server_public_key;
```

what I want to do is first encrypt a plaintext with client's private key and then server's public key.

```
unsigned char *plaintext =
    (unsigned char *)"Hello";
int encrypted_length= rsa_prv_encrypt(plaintext, strlen(plaintext), client_private_key, encrypted);
int encrypted_length2 = rsa_pub_encrypt(encrypted, encrypted_length, server_public_key, encrypted2);
```

encrypted_length2 is always -1, which means something went wrong with the encryption.

I have tested the following scenarios to ensure that the functions are working fine  :
Encrypt with clients private key -> Decrypt with clients public key
Encrypt with clients public key -> Decrypt with clients private key key

However the double encryption seems not to be working and I don't know why.
Any idea what might be the problem and the second function always return's -1?

Comment: Such a scheme doesn't make sense, and won't work at all when client modulus is greater than the server modulus. Also, openssl has no methods named `rsa_prv_encrypt` or `rsa_pub_encrypt`.

Answer (score 0):

RSA can’t encrypt data larger than the key size. For example an RSA 4096 key can only encrypt 4096 bits of data.

However, 11 bytes are going to be reserved for padding. So, for example, the maximum payload you can encrypt with a 4096 bit RSA key is 501 bytes. Similarly the limit is 245 bytes for an RSA 2048 bit key.

The output of RSA encryption is always equal to the key size (for example 512 or 256 bytes).

This means you can’t encrypt an RSA encrypted blob with a key of the same size unless you do “raw rsa encryption”, which doesn’t do padding (because 256 > 245 and 512 > 501).

If you want to sign data, however, it’s probably best to compute a sha, and then sign the sha, rather than to try unpadded encryption.